# Network rendering disconnects computers

Tags: rendering, network

I'm trying to use the Network Render over several computers and everything starts out great. All of my slaves connect just fine. After awhile of things processing though, the slaves get disconnected (Or at least they don't show up anymore) and I'm left with a few error ridden frames. When I go to check blender running on the slaves, they haven't crashed or anything. Does anyone know what might be happening?

Comment: As they are still running I would guess blender is keeping the machines 100% busy, causing slow responses that timeout. If you are using all the ram and pushing other parts out to swap space this could make for longer response times. It can be hard to tell without looking at the machines while working.